# Grails 2.4.4 & asset-pipeline 2.5.7 - disable source mapping during production

Tags: grails, plugins, configuration, asset-pipeline, source-maps

I'm trying to prevent Grails from serving source maps to minified files.

I checked the asset-pipeline [plugin's page](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html) and from there it seems like the solution should be:

```
Config.groovy:
environment {
  production {
    grails.assets.enableSourceMaps = false
  }
}
```

This doesn't seems to work, i can still access the unminified file via the browser's console.

I even tried to apply this config to any environment and it's still not working.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @DavidBrewer yeah i did, it seems like a version problem. once i upgraded the plugin to a version > 2.5.7 it worked just fine!